# Storing Values passed Between Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a question. I want to save variables passed between two activities on android.

For example:

We have `A` `B` and `C` activities and let us assume to pass a variable from activity `B` to `A`. For example we have a variable named `size` in activity `B` and another variable named `turn` in `C`.

B->A (get size)
C->A (get turn, but variable size lost)

...but when we go to `C`, function to take `turn` i lost `size` variable which earlier was taken on `B`. How can i store them? I tried static and it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: static should work. There is probably something in your code that is resetting the variable

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get this done via a Singleton object.

[Here's](https://gist.github.com/Akayh/5566992) an example implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Using Custom Class implement Serializable for Store Data

```
public class SomeData implement Serializable {
    public int size;
    public int turn;
}
```

Store Values

```
SomeData data = new SomeData();
data.turn = 2;
data.size = 4;

Intent i = new Intent(this, SomethingClass.class);
i.putExtra("Data", data);
startActivity(i);
```

Load Value

```
SomeData data = (SomeData) getIntent.getSerializable("Data");
```

instead data.turn = something, you can use get/setter methods just like below.

```
public class SomeData implement Serializable {
    private int size;
    private int turn;

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public int getTurn() {
        return turn;
    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public void setTurn(int turn) {
        this.turn = turn;
    }
}
```

Comment: On Android Parcable is the preferred method http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/parcelable-vs-java-serialization-in-android-app-development

Comment: oh, and this doesn't answer the question